# How to keep router’s component not be reused in Vue3.0

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

I want to use `transition`,`keep-alive`,`router-view` at the same time in App.vue. And I want the router's component not be reused.

This is the doc in [vue-router](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

> One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from /users/johnny to /users/jolyne, the same component instance will be reused.

in Vue2.x,I can use key to keep router's component not be reused.

```
<transition>
  <keep-alive>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" ></router-view>
  </keep-alive>
</transition>
```

But in Vue3.0 the code is like below.

```
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <transition>
    <keep-alive>
      <component :is="Component" />
    </keep-alive>
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

Someone can help to keep router's component not be reused in Vue3.0? use key in router-view cant work.

Comment: Did you try to place `:key="$route.fullPath"` on `<component>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided as a comment by [Michal Levý](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381282/michal-lev%c3%bd):
Place `:key="$route.fullPath"` on `<component>`

Comment: yes，thanks, I want @ this guy,but I failed.